# What are the three worlds in the Rig Veda

Tags: rig-veda, varuna

I was reading a book called ['Astronomical Myths:Myths of the Heavens'](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Astronomical_Myths.html?id=igMLAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by John F. Blake and I came across this at [Page 11-13](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=igMLAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> "Thus to the earth they gave the name  P'RTHOVI, "the wide expanse;"
>   the blue and star-bespangled heavens they called VARUNA, "the vault;"
>   and beneath it in the region of the clouds they enthroned the light
>   DYAUS, i.e. "the luminous air."

followed by this image

[image]

Upon researching further, I only found that the heavens are called 'Dyaus' and the mid-region is called 'Antariksh'. So how accurate is this image and what do we know about the three worlds in Vedic era?

Comment: Could you add the exact reference from the book like which page number etc. Also add source of the book from where you're reading. That would help us to do further analysis/reading. Thanks

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It's from the book Astronomical Myths:Based on Flammarion's History of the Heavens by John F. Blake - pg 12. You can find the book Project Guteneberg

Comment: Thanks for sharing details, I updated your question. You can check once.

Comment: The three worlds are Bhur(earth) for men,Bhuvan(space) for ancestors and Swarga(heaven) for Gods and are named everyday via Gayatri as 'Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha..'  by twice-born.